# No migrations to apply

Tags: python, django, django-syncdb

```
$python manage.py syncdb
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, contenttypes, auth, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

the error printscreen

[image]

i don't know what the problem !

Comment: What is your question? Does `manage.py makemigrations` work?

Comment: i try to syncdb this is the error that appear i don't know what the problem !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the command line output says the problem is that you changed the models. The solution is to run `python manage.py makemigrations` and then `python manage.py migrate`.

Answer (score 2):

The Best Thing You can do is, Delete the existing database.
In my case, I were using phpMyAdmin SQL database, so I manually delete the created database overthere. 
Again run the following Commands:

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

`python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>`

`python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 2):

IT COULD BE BECAUSE YOU HAVE NOT YET REGISTERED YOUR APP IN SETTINGS.PY inside this file install your app (put the name of your app in quotes) after you can make python3 manage.py makemigrations and then python3 manage.py migrate (it can be python3 or python without the 3 ):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'new_app_name',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friend after all these steps if there was still this problem.

1- Clear all tables in the database.

2-Clear all history in the migrations folder of your project directory.

3-python manage.py makemigrations

4-python manage.py migrate